# How to start with javascript code obfuscation? Not looking for tools

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I would love to learn how to do javascript obfuscation. I have been searching through the web but I have not found anything to start with. Only posts about tools and more tools...

Is there any book?
What techinques are there?
Can someone show me some link to understand javascript obfuscation?
There are several ways to do it?
Is this explained in the javascript or ecmascript documentation?

I'm not looking for any tool. I only want to understand it and learn it.

Comment: Generally it's just the minifying and compressing code, then renaming variables and items to be non-human readable.

Comment: I would like to read some tutorial. Thanks for the info

Comment: @IraBaxter that is a recommendation which will lead to this question being closed. Please avoid suggesting other sites unless you are familiar with their scope. Resource requests are explicitly off topic on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @enderland: This question is going to get closed anyway by SO naysayers (already on hold).  If you have a better suggestion, it would by helpful to the OP to provide it.

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/auditmark/owasp-eu-tour-2013-lisbon-pedro-fortuna-protecting-java-script-source-code-using-obfuscation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most comprehensive obfuscation method is converting all JavaScript code to non-alphanumeric characters. [This blog post](http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html) covers how it works and links to a converter tool in case you change your mind.

Comment: Thank you Makaze, I was looking for something like this. People downvoted my question but is a bit difficult to find info about this. Only tools and more  tools... :)

Comment: Some other methods include changing all variable and function names to single letters or even using indexes in arrays where possible.

Comment: @dac777 They downvoted because this is not really an appropraite question for SO. SO if for helping you fix problems in your code, or understanding how code works, not for design advice or tutoring.

Comment: Makaze thank you again. Barmar maybe this question is for another StackExchange site... Thanks for your advice

Comment: non-alphanumeric obfuscation may look effective but it's 0% stealthy, file gets larger and with a parser you can simplify it back to the original source, might be interesting in theory but in practice don't ever use it to obfuscate your javascript...